# clojure improve readability of filter a two-dimensional list

Tags: clojure, code-readability

The current code takes a input like:
`[[:k1 0] [:k1 1] [:k2 2]]`
and organize the items that have the same keyword inside a list:
`(([:k1 0] [:k1 1]) ([:k2 2]))`

the following code works, but I feel that can be improved. The nested
`map #(filter`  looks ugly, I think I can use clojure `for` function to produce the same result with a elegantly code.

**how can I improve readability?**

```
(defn list-of-equals [itens]
  (let [get-key (fn [[k]] k)
        keys (->> itens (map get-key) distinct)
        pairs (map #(filter (fn [[k]]
                              (= % k)) itens)  keys)]
      pairs))
```

Comment: `(vals (group-by first itens))`

Comment: well, thats looks readable ._. thanks

Comment: sorry, if I find a moment to write out a full explanation of why that replaces the code, I will

Comment: Your algorithm needs improvement because of its complexity. Readability is a second concern in this case. Observe that it needs to traverse the entire sequence per distinct key which performs in `O(n²)`. @noisesmith solution solves both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you have to iterate over the list for every distinct key. If you were to use `for`, it might look something like this.

```
(defn for-filter [items val]
  (for [i items
        :when (= (first i) (first val))]
    i))
```

While this might be a little cleaner, using the standard library can make it more succinct. If we do a group-by operation, we can collect all the items with the same key in a single pass.

```
(group-by first items)
    => {:k1 [[:k1 0] [:k1 1]], :k2 [[:k2 2]]}
```

You can discard the keys with `vals`

```
(vals (group-by first items))
    => ([[:k1 0] [:k1 1]] [[:k2 2]])
```

This is a little different than your solution

```
 (([:k1 0] [:k1 1]) ([:k2 2]))
```

vs

```
 ([[:k1 0] [:k1 1]] [[:k2 2]]))
```

If that's important:

```
(map #(into () %) result)
```

The final solution looks like:

```
(defn list-of-equals [items]
    (->> (vals (group-by first items))
         (map #(into () %))))
```

Comment: fyi - clojure's `=` thinks vectors and lists are equal if they have equal contents

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to be a little more accurate.